# Setting EditText from SQLite Table at ViewPager position

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-viewpager

So I have an edittext with a save button. When you enter text and press save the text is saved in COLUMN_ROUTENOTE and the position is saved in COLUMN_ROUTENOTEPOSITION, now I want it that when you close the app and go back to a position in the viewpager the edittext is populated with the route note that you saved at that position previously. I'm new to programming and unsure how to accomplish this. `

Heres my viewpager with the save button that adds the values to the database and where I need to set the edittext and my viewpager position.

```
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            RouteNote routeNote = new RouteNote();
            routeNote.set_routeNote(noteEditText.getText().toString());
            dbHandler.addRouteNote(routeNote);

            RouteNote routeNotePosition = new RouteNote();
            routeNotePosition.set_routeNotePosition(position);
            dbHandler.addRouteNotePosition(routeNotePosition);
        }});

    Cursor n = db.rawQuery("SELECT routeNotePosition FROM checked_routes", null);
    db.rawQuery("SELECT routeNote FROM checked_routes", null);

      n.moveToPosition(position);
      n.getString(position);

    noteEditText.setText(???);
```

heres my db handler where I add the routenote and position

```
/////Add route note row to table
public void addRouteNote(RouteNote routeNote){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NOTE, routeNote.get_routeNote());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES , null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    db.close();
}
/////Add route note position to table
public void addRouteNotePosition(RouteNote routeNotePosition){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ROUTENOTEPOSITION, routeNotePosition.get_routeNotePosition());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES , null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    db.close();
}
```

and heres my routeNote class

```
public class RouteNote {

private String routeNote;
private int routeNotePosition;

public void set_routeNote(String routeNote){ this.routeNote = routeNote;
}

public String get_routeNote(){
    return routeNote;
}

 public void set_routeNotePosition(int routeNotePosition){ this.routeNotePosition = routeNotePosition;
}

 public int get_routeNotePosition(){
    return routeNotePosition;
}
}
```

Thank you for any help

Edit: still looking for help thanks!

Working:

```
        Cursor n = db.rawQuery(" SELECT routeNote FROM route_note WHERE routeNotePosition = " + Integer.toString(position),null);

    if (n.getCount() >= 1) {
        n.moveToFirst();
        String note = n.getString(n.getColumnIndex("routeNote"));
        noteEditText.setText(note);
        n.close();
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should save the Text and Last position in the database and check as part of positioning if data exists and if so load it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do but I'm unsure how to accomplish this

Comment: `int rnp = n.getInt(n.getColumnIndex("roueNotePosition")); // get routeNotesPosition` . t is missing in rou**t**eNote, should be `int rnp = n.getInt(n.getColumnIndex("routeNotePosition")); // get routeNotesPosition`, but that result in column not found in table type error.

Comment: so I was able to get it to work! it was basically your answer but I changed it slightly. Thank you! I put the working one in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a (the same) row holds both the **routeNotePosition** and **routeNote** then :-

```
Cursor n = db.rawQuery(" SELECT routeNotePosition, routeNote FROM checked_routes", null);

String rnp = n.getString(0); // get the routenoteposition
noteEditText.setText(n.getString(1)); //Set the EditText
```

If **routeNotePosition** hold the position of the **RouteNote**  and that it's an integer and also assuming that the required **roueNotePosition** is in the first row ( else add a moveToPosition for cursor **n** before setting **rnp**)

---

**Note!!** changed 3rd line of code to use **`SELECT routeNote ....`** instead of `SELECT roueNote` (i.e missing **t**)as per comment in question.

---

```
Cursor n = db.rawQuery(" SELECT routeNotePosition FROM checked_routes",null);
Cursor x = db.rawQuery(" SELECT routeNote FROM checked_routes",null);

int rnp = n.getInt(n.getColumnIndex("routeNotePosition"),-1); // get routeNotesPosition

if ((x.getCount() > rnp) || rnp < 0) {
    x.moveToPosition(rnp);
    noteEditText.setText(x.getString(getColumnIndex(routeNote)));
} else {
    // handle invalid position i.e. greater than rows in cursor
}
```

Note `getColumnIndex(column_name_as_string)` gets the position of the column, within the cursor, according to the name of the column. Using specific positions can end of causing issues and or involve greater maintenance.

What this is doing is :-

- a) creating 2 cursors, each having just the 1 column (much as you
  did, except that you discarded the second cursor by not assigning it
  to a variable. So after a there are 2 cursors (**n** and **x**).
- b) extracting the routeNotesPosition from the first cursor into an
  integer variable called **rnp** (this I assume being the position i.e
  the row that holds the associated roueNotes) (`int rnp = .......`).  The -1 `getInt` is the default value, used if the an Int cannot be returned (so the next step checks for this situation as well).
- c) The rnp is checked to ensure that the second cursor has at least
  that many rows (noting that position is an offset so the first row is
  0, whilst count returns the number of rows so starts at 1 if any rows
  exist). (`if (x.getCount() > rnp`).
- d) Cursor x is moved to the position as per **rnp**.
- e) The    **EditText** is set according to the data held in the
  **routeNotes** column.

I can't see that the following code that you've used would work. You are saying move the cursor to row x (*position*) and then get the data from the column at offest x. It would work only if x were 0. If position was 1 then the it would fail as there is no offset 1 in cursor n (it just has the 1 column which would be offset 0 so `n.getString(position)` would fail as the `SELECT` only specifies 1 column).

```
  n.moveToPosition(position);
  n.getString(position);
```

My guess, is that you are looking for something along the lines of the second example. However, perhaps combining the **routeNotePosition** with the **routeNote** would be advantageous.

Note the code provided has been written on the fly, thus it may have errors in it. It's intended more as a guide.

---

Added according to comments.
The following change to the second example should handle getting the correct **roueNotePosition** row :-

```
Cursor n = db.rawQuery(" SELECT routeNotePosition FROM checked_routes WHERE routeNotePosition = " + Integer.toString(position),null);
```

Where `position` is an integer containing the `ViewPager` position. The same change could aslo be applied to the first example.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for answering I will give it a shot tonight and let you know how it works. The only thing I'm thinking looking at it is I want to access the routeNote where routeNotePosition == position. Where position is the current viewpager page the user is on. So say the user is on position 57 of the viewpager then I would need the routeNote at routeNotePosition == 57. I hope that makes sense

Comment: So I was trying to get this to work and I still cannot for some reason. I was able to accomplish what I wanted but in a totally different way that I know is not the right way to do it. I edited my original post to show how I got it to work and how I was trying to implement your solution. I would much prefer your solution if I can get it to work.